# AutoCompleteBox does not get correct value in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, autocompletebox

I am currently working on a WPF C# project. I am using the AutoCompleteBox WPF control  but I am having a problem getting the value out of the box.

Assuming that the autocomplete box is for a server name, when I type 'loc' the popup box will show up 'localhost' and I select the value from the dropdown box.

When I then try and submit the form and attempt to get the value of the box it will get the value of what I type not what I selected i.e. the value will be 'loc'.

Below is the code I am using to populate the AutoComplete items for the control

```
using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    List<string> serverArr = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        serverArr.Add(reader["his_server"].ToString());
    }
    txtServer.ItemsSource = serverArr;
}
```

I am getting the value from the autocompletebox by saying txtServer.Text;

### Update

As suggested by @Tom Studee I tried using the txtServer.selectedItem which works fine when an item from the auto complete is selected. However, if a value is typed which isn't inside the drop down auto complete then it fails with a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, when I select a suggested item from the list it also updates the `Text` property. How is your `AutoCompleteBox` defined?

Comment: @Meleak the SelectedItem works fine if a suggested item is clicked. The problem now is if the user types a value which isn't in the auto complete suggestion it causes the null pointer exception

Comment: Well, are you looking for the selecteditem or the text? If the user selects an item that isn't in the list then null is the expected result. If you are looking for the text value then use the `Text` property, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Meleak, I need to be able to get either one. I need to get the text if it is a new entry and I need to get the selected item if the user selects one of the suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.Text` use the `.SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Thanks this did work to stop get null pointer exception i created an if statement to check that .text wasn't null. thanks for the help

Answer (score -3):

You might be able to

```
   string cbValue;
   if (SelectedIndex == -1) cbValue = .Text; else cbValue = .SelectedItem;
```

Comment: there is not a selectedindex option for the autocompletebox.

Comment: I had .SelectedItem part right.  I will remember not to try and answer any of you questions in the future.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the .SelectedItem I was talking about the selectedIndex. As you can see from my accepted answer the .SelectedItem is working fine for me but what you had didn't work. Can't remember why now was too long ago.